# Condition that the product of orthogonal projections is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

We need to show that the product of orthogonal projection is orthogonal iff the projections commute.

$\Rightarrow$ Let $P, Q$ be the orthogonal projections, we know $P^2 = P$ and $Q^2 =Q$. Also, $PQ$ is a projection $(PQ)(PQ) = PQ = P^2Q^2$. From here, how do I go about showing the projections commute.(I intially though we can take inverse, but as mentioned in the comments the projections can be singular).

$\Leftarrow$ We can show that PQ is a projection given P and Q commute but how do I show it is orthogonal.

Comment: Most projections are singular. How are you “taking inverse?” Besides, didn’t you use the fact that $P$ and $Q$ commute to show that $PQ$ is a projection?

Comment: @amd. The projections $P$ and $Q$ can be singular and I have edited the question. There are two parts to the question 1) if $PQ$ is a projection, show $P$ and $Q$ commute, 2) if $P$ and $Q$ commute, show $PQ$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: How do you define an *orthogonal* projection in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the following statements are equivalent:

- $R$ is an orthogonal projection
- $R^2=R=R^*$
- $R^*R=R$

Then

If $PQ=QP$, then $(PQ)^*PQ=Q^*P^*PQ=QPQ=PQ^2=PQ$.

Conversely, if $PQ$ is an orthogonal projection, we have $QP=Q^*P^*=(PQ)^*=PQ$.